# Trying to avoid goto function in my Arduino circuit that attempts to create a "Smart Waiter"

Tags: arduino, goto

Basically, I am making an Arduino Uno project that involves creating a smart waiter that:

1. Will have a glass holder on top of the basic Arduino chassis. The sensors will be:

   - 4 Infrared Sensors, one on each side
   - 2 Line Sensors, one left and one right
   - Light Sensor, one the cup holder
2. It will also have:

   - 2 Servo Motors, one left and right
   - 1 LED showing cup status
3. It will:

   - Move along a black line that will be taped on the floor of the HOP
   - Will sense people on all sides, and pause when it senses close bodies
   - Will stop indefinitely if it senses that the glass has been lifted
   - Will start again in 15 seconds if it doesn’t sense movement of glass OR will start again when glass is put down
   - After glass has been put down, LED will turn from green to red
   - Robot will continue to move, ignoring all obstacles, until it reaches filling station
   - Will stop at filling station, where filler will replace glass and press Arduino hard reset button

My Code is:

```
#include <Servo.h>
int redLED = 5;
int yellowLED = 6;
int greenLED = 7;
int cup1 = 0;
int picked = 1;
int lineright = 0;
int lineleft = 0;
int sensorright = 0;
int sensorleft = 0;
int sensorfront = 0;
int sensorback = 0;
int sensorpinright = 1;
int sensorpinleft = 2;
int sensorpinfront = 3;
int sensorpinback = 4;
Servo servoright;
Servo servoleft;
void setup ()
{
  servoright.attach (9);
  servoleft.attach (10);
  pinMode (redLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (greenLED, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
   sensorright = digitalRead (sensorpinright);
   sensorleft = digitalRead (sensorpinleft);
   sensorfront = digitalRead (sensorpinfront);
   sensorback = digitalRead (sensorpinback);
   lineleft = analogRead (1);
   lineright = analogRead (2);
   cup1 = analogRead (3);
 if (sensorright < 0 && sensorleft < 0 && sensorfront < 0 && sensorback < 0)
  {
    digitalWrite (led1, GREEN);
    startfresh:
    if (lineleft < 800)
    {
      servoleft.write (180);
      servoright.write (180);
    }
    else
    {
      if (lineright < 800)
      {
        servoright.write (0);
        servoleft.write (0);
      }
      else
      {
        servoright.write (0);
        servoleft.write (180);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
      servoright.write (93);
      servoleft.write (93);
      if (picked < 1)
      {
        while (cup1<500)
        {
          digitalWrite (yellowLED, HIGH);
          picked = 1;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        digitalWrite (yellowLED, LOW);
        digitalWrite (redLED, HIGH);
        goto startfresh;
      }
      delay (2000)
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do with my code is to avoid the `goto` function at the end. However, I cannot find any way to restructure this with the limitation of only 2 functions. In this case, the `goto` function seems fine, but I am not sure. Is there any simple way to restructure this?

Comment: What goto function?

What limit of 2 functions?

You can define as many functions as you want; there is no limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make startfresh as function

```
 if (sensorright < 0 && sensorleft < 0 && sensorfront < 0 && sensorback < 0)
  {
    digitalWrite (led1, GREEN);
    startfresh();
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
      servoright.write (93);
      servoleft.write (93);
      if (picked < 1)
      {
        while (cup1<500)
        {
          digitalWrite (yellowLED, HIGH);
          picked = 1;
        }
        delay (2000);
      }
      else
      {
        digitalWrite (yellowLED, LOW);
        digitalWrite (redLED, HIGH);
        startfresh();
      }
    }
  }
}

void startfresh() {
  if (lineleft < 800)
  {
    servoleft.write (180);
    servoright.write (180);
  }
  else
  {
    if (lineright < 800)
    {
      servoright.write (0);
      servoleft.write (0);
    }
    else
    {
      servoright.write (0);
      servoleft.write (180);
    }
  }
}
```